# error 105 mysql FOREIGN KEYS

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am trying to create database table and get them connected by mysql FOREIGN KEYS. I have ensured that my data types are identical. I also ensure that my tables are made before added the FK. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `af_feeds` (
  `id` int(64) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hash` char(255) NOT NULL,
  `seed_id` int(64) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(64) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `content` longtext,
  `publishing_date` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `link` text NOT NULL,
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `create_date` int(64) NOT NULL,
  `update_date` int(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `hash` (`hash`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`seed_id`) REFERENCES `af_seeds`(`id`)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `af_categories`(`id`)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ON DELETE CASCADE
```

MySQL said:

## 1005 - Can't create table 'estafeed_rss.af_feeds' (errno: 150) (Details…)

[image]

```
--
-- Table structure for table `af_categories`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `af_categories` (
  `id` int(64) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `icon` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `create_date` int(64) NOT NULL,
  `update_date` int(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `af_seeds`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `af_seeds` (
  `id` int(64) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `link` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(64) NOT NULL,
  `loading_times` int(64) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `loading_each` int(64) NOT NULL,
  `last_loading` int(64) NOT NULL,
  `create_date` int(64) NOT NULL,
  `update_date` int(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `url` (`link`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

Comment: Are there more details linked from the word "details", by any chance?

Comment: Please post af_seeds and af_categories too.

Comment: Fields seed_id and category_id should probably be unsigned - they need to have the same properties as their parents. Make sure you use InnoDB as the engine. Also, you're missing the ending parenthesis.

Comment: Great, I'm glad to hear it. :)